# Dart - assigning class to factory constructor

Tags: dart

I have found an interesting (to me) place in Dart code:

```dart
factory Uri(
      {String scheme,
      String userInfo,
      String host,
      int port,
      String path,
      Iterable<String> pathSegments,
      String query,
      Map<String, dynamic /*String|Iterable<String>*/ > queryParameters,
      String fragment}) = _Uri;  // <==== here
```

and then:

```dart
class _Uri implements Uri {
...
}
```

It looks like the class `_Uri` is assigned to the factory constructor. I don't think I have read about it in the language tour or anywhere else. What is this 'technique' called? How does it work? Are there any special requirements for the factory constructor and the class for this to work?

Comment: It's called a "redirecting factory constructor".  It is not common, and it is not very well documented outside of the Dart language specification.

Comment: @jamesdlin Found this: https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/2009. Please add an answer so that I can accept it. BTW it's under 10.6.2 in the current language specification.